# Change theme background color for eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

For luna, I have downloaded eclipse color theme and changed my text editor color to 'Solarized Dark'. How can I change my project explorer background color and other windows other than the editor? I have picked Dark Theme but I can't seem to customize dark theme to match the text editor background color. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"Any help is appreciated"

You need to change some CSS files, 
You will find them here :

C:...\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20141126-1957\css\

The next step is to find the right file and the right color to change (this is your part, i'm to lazy for it ^^ But it works)

You need to restart eclipse to see the changes.

Enjoy your customisation ! ;)

Comment: Ok, did or tried to. I could not change the project explorer window color. Drives me nuts. I think I replaced boat loads of dark looking background colors. Did not think eclipse/swt had so many bugs. Will try again tomorrow when I have some free time.